# JOptionPane on WebService

Tags: java, web-services

I'm trying to use the JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() method in a webservice, but somehow, the message dialog won't show up at all on the client-side. This is just to know if the program executed a line or not, since I can't really debug normally. Any ideas?

Comment: why you dont use System.out.println("message")?

Comment: Because on a webservice, you can't see the console on the client's side.

Comment: Looking for a problem on the client side?

Comment: You cannot use a GUI component like `JOptionPane` with web services! You should use logging for that. And usually console output will be logged somewhere to, e.g. Glassfish will put it in its `server.log`. There are also several options for debugging web services.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, you can not use GUI components in your web service.  You can try printing to standard out but this should be handled by [logging](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) of some sorts.